# Flutter plugin not shown on Development Pods

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am trying to edit a flutter plugin code for iOS (Swift). I read in the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-2c-add-ios-platform-code-swifthm) that you can edit the iOS plugin code using XCode itself.

As mentioned there, I built the code first and then launched my_plugin/example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace  in XCode. But I could not find the plugin swift file to edit in the Pods/Development Pods.

Where can I find the flutter plugin code to edit in XCode?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your example depends on your plugin? Check my_plugin/example/pubspec.yaml. You need to add `my_plugin` under `dependencies` (probably using a local path). Then run `flutter pub get` in your example, and it should then appear in Xcode